# what would be the downside of using BLOB?

Tags: html, blob

I'm looking to store a video in a database as a BLOB type.
The video will be playing back using progressive downloading.

Are there any problems that I might face?
Using the html5 video player it would look like this:

```
<video width="800" height="450" src=BLOB type=""/></video>
```

Comment: what have you tried,what didnt work? because there is actually no issue in your question.

Comment: Im using progressive downloading with the file being accessed on the file system and i am not looking for a solution, rather any issues that may arise because i have never done this before and i have 200M users that come to my website every day.

Comment: belongs to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ please delete it here and open it there.

Answer (score 0):

By storing video files in the database it means your data-tier is invoked every time there's a request for the video which will be very expensive from an IO perspective, also given that (AFAIK) most database libraries don't let you access binary information from an offset it means you won't be able to provide seek support to consumers (they'd all have to download the video fully first).

Storing video-files in a database can be acceptable depending on the load (how many requests will be made for this video?), if you're employing any form of caching so it doesn't have to hit the database so often (e.g. storing the whole video in memcached), how big the videos are (if they're just 6-second Vine-style videos then you'll get away with it, if these are 20GB 4K hi-def documentary videos then probably not).

Out of curiosity, why not use a third-party video hosting service like YouTube or use a CDN to host your video files?

Answer (score 0):

**Some downside of storing Blobs**

When your DB grows bigger and bigger it will become harder to backup. Restoring a backup of a table with over 100 GB of data is not something that makes you happy.

Another thing that get is that all the table management functions get slower and slower as the dataset grows.
But this can be overcome by making your data table just contain 2 fields: ID and BLOB.

Retrieving data (by primary key) will likely only become a problem long after you hit a wall with backing up the dataset.

Answer (score -1):

We had similar situation in pas project where we saved video and audio on disk and researched if there are any benefits to keep them in database. What we've found is that file system is easiest and primitive solution, whenever you have complex requirement your choice is database, but keep in mind these:

1. Saving on disk offers simplicity, i.e. you can later change the structure of folders and move files between them relatively easy. Typically you would want to distinguish between audio and video files, corrupted files, formats of files, group files by date, etc. and keep those in sub-folders. So whenever you need more folders you can easily add them
2. Think in advance about retain policies when for example, newest media you would keep for 30 days, then move into different disk or whatever. You need clear understanding how you would achieve this with database
3. CDN. It was really easy to spread out files through servers. With database it depends on your scenario and might be easier or more challenging
4. Database will add overhead as you can not just access the file through URI and need some middle-ware code that will communicate to db
5. Database will be quite helpful if you need analysis of data or Business Intelligence support, transactions and indexing

Comment: So would the user actually need to download the video completely before viewing? like Dia said? thats one of my greatest concerns. By the way youtube uses BLOB.

Comment: @user3283552 How do you know how YouTube stores their videos?

Comment: As for downloading a video - no, not necessarily if you will use streaming such as smooth streaming extension for IIS. But this has nothing to do with the way you save the video. I suggest you to be more specific in what you are asking

Comment: As for youtube - I doubt, here is theirs high-level architecture and I do not see anything about stroing the video as BLOBs: http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture